Is integral extension of rings a local property?
I want a counterexample that shows integral extension is not a local property (although it's known that integrally closed domain is local property):
Let $f:A\to B$ be a ring morphism between commutative rings ( WTG we can assume it's a ring extension). If $f$ is integral, then for every prime ideal ${\frak{p}}\in A$, $f_{\frak{p}}:A_{\frak{p}}\to B_{\frak{p}}$ is also integral. My guess is that the converse is NOT true. Is there any counterexample?

It is true, because integral closure commutes with localization

Or see Stacks 034K for a slightly different argument

@leoli1, Thank you!
